# I need to connect my samsung tablet to my laptop to use it as a drawing pad but it is not working

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I need to connect my tablet to my ASUS computer but it is not working.  I've tried a usb port but it still doesn't work.  Please don't ignore this text and please awnser it.*

Comment: You can't just connect a device and expect it to do whatever you want ! The device must be designed to do such a thing. You should need drivers and even software ro make it possible.

Answer (score 1):

**GfxTablet** shall make it possible to use your Android  tablets like a graphics tablet using the network instead of USB. 
It consists of two components: The Android app and the input drivers for your computer.

The driver creates a virtual "*network tablet*" on your PC that is controlled by your Android device.

The GfxTablet app sends motions and touch events via UDP to a specified host on port 40118.

So, you can use your Android tablet or smartphone to control the PC and, for instance
use GIMP (Image Manipulation Program) with your Android tablet as a graphics tablet (even pressure-sensitive, if your hardware supports it).

Check the [Homepage.](https://gfxtablet.bitfire.at)

Comment: Cool stuff, never knew it's actually possible. Linux only, though... Still, +1